# gdb - No hardware breakpoint support in the target

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, gdb

I'm tring to set hardware breakpoint using gdb hbreak command

```
hbreak *address
```

but I'm getting the following error: "No hardware breakpoint support in the target".

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Try the start command first. GDB often says that when the program has not been started yet even if there is hardware support (this is a very misleading message in this context).

Comment: This was also raised on the mailing list at: https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2010-11/msg00075.html

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware may not be supporting hardware breakpoints or perhaps you are out of available hw-breakpoint registers. You can still use software breakpoints as a fix.